# cassandra-driver-core: pass list values to parameterized SimpleStatement

Tags: java, cassandra, cql3

I'm currently writing a very basic CQL access layer using the official Datastax Driver (V2.0) and struggling a bit on passing parameter values to a statement.

Here's an example

**Column family (simplified)**

```
USE myKeyspace;

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    myId timeuuid,
    myTypeId int,
    myVal varchar,
    PRIMARY_KEY( myId, myTypeId )
);

CREATE INDEX MyTable_myTypeID 
    ON MyTable( myTypeId );
```

The basic idea is storing some event data with multiple values (per "event"), that's why I'm using the combined PK. Every event has its time-based UUID, there might be multiple entries per typeId. *Does that even make sense from a modelling perspective?*

What I'm trying to do now is fetching only entries for an event with a selection of 'typeIds'.

```
public void myQueryCode() {

    Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
    builder.withPort( 9142 );
    builder.addContactPoints( "127.0.0.1" );
    cluster = builder.build();
    Session session = cluster.connect( "myKeyspace" );

    List<Integer> typeFilter = new ArrayList<> ();
    typeFilter.add( 1 );
    typeFilter.add( 2 );

    Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement( 
        "SELECT * FROM MyTable where myId = ?" +
        " AND myTypeId IN (?,?)" +
        " ALLOW FILTERING",
        UUID.randomUUID(),
        typeFilter );

    ResultSet result = session.execute( stmt );

    // do something with results
}
```

However, I'm just getting an exception deep down in serialization of the Statement's values.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 4 or 0 byte int (8)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:172)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
```

I'm not sure on passing the list as second parameter, the driver is taking the parameter, but maybe that is only suitable for inserts on collection-typed columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the List you are passing is being forced into the second parameter and this causes the InvalidQueryException.

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement( 
        "SELECT * FROM MyTable where myId = ?#1" +
        " AND myTypeId IN (?#2,?#3)" +
        " ALLOW FILTERING",
        #1 UUID.randomUUID(),
        #2 typeFilter );
```

Since typeFilter is a list the driver then attempts to put a List Collection object into parameter 2 and things go wonky. This is because when you run statements like this (without preparing) the driver is unable to check the types, [Comment in code](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/55b60db5767af26d4cf4618c495e0f760096c25c/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/SimpleStatement.java#L68-L76). If instead you passed in

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement( 
            "SELECT * FROM MyTable where myId = ?#1" +
            " AND myTypeId IN (?#2,?#3)" +
            " ALLOW FILTERING",
            #1 UUID.randomUUID(),
            #2 typeFilter.get(0)
            #3 typeFilter.get(1));
```

You would be fine. Or if you had prepared the statement first you would have been warned with a compile time error.

Comment: Thanks you, as I thought... might get tricky when you're dealing with varying typeFilter list lengths, then you'd have to put all your query parameter values in a Object array and pass it as parameter list to the SimpleQuery (original code adapts the number of placeholders/wildcards).

However, I think I'm better off with the BoundStatement which rather handles like a traditional PreparedStatement with index- or alias-based parameter handling and type-specific setters.

The only problem left: I'd like to have the type in the PK, but Cassandra 2.0 does not support "IN" clauses on PK columns.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your first question, does it make sense from a modeling perspective to store "some event data with multiple values (per "event"), that's why I'm using the combined PK. Every event has its time-based UUID, there might be multiple entries per typeId," yes absolutely. This is a similar scenario to the one the Cassandra team uses in its data modeling example of a Music Service: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_music_service_c.html.

Look for a minor glitch in your code because I can do your example on the command line:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    myId timeuuid,
    myTypeId int,
    myVal varchar,
    PRIMARY_KEY( myId, myTypeId )
);
CREATE INDEX MyTable_myTypeID 
    ON MyTable( myTypeId );
insert into mytable( myid, mytypeid, myval) VALUES (d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3, 100, 'somechar')
insert into mytable( myid, mytypeid, myval) VALUES (d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3, 200, 'anotherchar')
SELECT * FROM MyTable where myId = d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3 AND myTypeId IN (100,200) ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Output is:

```
myid                                 | mytypeid | myval
--------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3 |      100 |    somechar
 d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3 |      200 | anotherchar
```

Comment: Yes, it was a code glitch. 1 UUID plus a List of size 2 does not mean you're passing 3 parameters, actually its 1xUUID + 1x list type, causing a data type mismatch (2nd parameter is an integer, no a list of them).